# how to copy and rotate already animated objects

Tags: animation, workflow

I'm working on a circulair symetric design that has to be annimated (think gears in gears). Now I have animated one of the parts and would like to copy and paste the animation into the other parts. Is there an easy way to take an already animated part copy and paste it without having to redo the keyframes (I'm working in 6 fold symetry so that is 32 parts).

Comment: just use the same action that you have created

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy your object and parent it to an empty object, then transform the empty object.

If a copy already exists go to -> Dopesheet Editor, choose Action Editor, select the copy and choose the action from the original object.

To mirror the animation you can use negative scaling.

Comment: How would I go about parrenting an object to an empty object?

Comment: [Here](https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/objects/groups_and_parenting.html) is a description. Basically select the object which will be the child object first, select the parent object afterwards and press CTRL + P.

Answer (score 1):

Select each one of the other gears and set their active action to the action you have already created ( the animation you did to the first gear is stored as an action ) :

- select the object
- in Dope sheet set it to action Editor
- select the action of the first gear

Now all the gears share the same action

[image]